# iOS: Dynamically drawing on canvas(context)

Tags: objective-c, ios, math, cgcontext

I'm currently making an application which draws out a certain network of signs to the screen (on a CGContextRef). So far everything is going great, but now i'm finding myself in the situation that i can't solve this problem:

I'm trying to draw an object dynamically knowing only the line its on (have the start and ending point's x and y coordinates). With these i found the middle of the line, this is where the symbol should be drawn. With this information i found the angle of the line (with the top as 0). This is the information i have right now:

```
CGPoint firstLocation;
CGPoint secondLocation;
CGPoint middleLocation;

double x1 = firstLocation.x;
double y1 = firstLocation.y;
double x2 = middleLocation.x;
double y2 = middleLocation.y;

float a = (atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1) * (180/M_PI)) - 90;
```

I looked at using some transform function (like CGAffineTransform) on a CGRect, but this doesn't seem to work as i need to rotate the rect around it's center and a CGRect would only rotate around it's origin.

I want to create the following symbols with the above information:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, and if you need any more information please tell me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app I do something similar. I have a path that I add a transform to before drawing. The transform shifts the path to the midpoint, rotates it, and shifts it back:

```
// Rotate the path such that it points to the end coordinate
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(
  CGAffineTransformRotate(
    CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(middleLocation.x, middleLocation.y), 
    -a), 
  -middleLocation.x, -middleLocation.y);
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPoint points[8] = { ... these are the 8 points in my path ... };
CGPathAddLines(path, &t, points, 8);
```

You don't have to use `CGPathAddLines`, that was just the easiest way for me to construct the path. All of the `CGPathAdd...` functions can take a transform.

If you're not using `CGPath`, you could do a similar transform in the context itself by doing `CGContextTranslateCTM` and `CGContextRotateCTM`.

Comment: The line is fixed, i only need to rotate the symbol in the middle (the G so to speak) to match the angle that the line has. And i cant rotate the entire context as many other things will be drawn on the context.

Comment: You could translate/rotate the context right before you draw the G and translate/rotate back right after.

Comment: Oh does that actually work? if i draw a line from x = 0, y = 0 to x = 100, y = 100 wont it use the coordinates of the context thus making the transform useless?

Comment: It should apply the transforms to your line. You should try it and let me know!

Comment: this didn't seem to do the job. When i rotate the canvas all following things i draw on the context are for some reason stuck (the network is movable).

Comment: I see. Have you considered drawing the G as a transformed path?